# Extract date range from csv files and writing them into new files, Nothing happens

Tags: python, csv

Here is my code:

```
import os
import time

initial_date = '22.01.2015 02:00:00'
initial = time.mktime(time.strptime(initial_date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))

final_date = '15.04.2015 03:45:00'
final = time.mktime(time.strptime(final_date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))

path = 'Transfer\Praktikanten\2017-05-Sharon\M02_Modelldaten\Sofia_HW_032015_12\01.01.2015-31.12.2015_2014\22.02.2015-15.04.2015_201410XX'

directory = os.path.join("x:\\","path")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for files in directory:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
          f_in=open(file, 'r').readlines()

          Datum_Uhrzeit= []
          Wasserstand= []

          f_out = open('NEW_file','w')

          f_out.write(f_in[0])

          for i in range(1, len(f_in)):

            Datum_Uhrzeit= f_in[i].split(';',)[0]
            Wasserstand = f_in[i].split(';')[1]
            Datum_Uhrzeit= time.mktime(time.strptime(Datum_Uhrzeit, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))
            if initial <= Datum_Uhrzeit <= final:
                f_out.write(f_in[i])
                f_out.close()
```

I am trying to extract the given date time from all CSV files in the mentioned folder and write these data in a new_file.

Sample CSV file:
[CSV file headers and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viZC3.png)

The code returns no errors but it doesn't generate the new files.

Answer (score 2):

So I managed to solve it. Here is the code if anyone needs in the future:

```
import os
import time

initial_date = '22.02.2015 02:00:00'
initial = time.mktime(time.strptime(initial_date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))

final_date = '15.04.2015 03:45:00'
final = time.mktime(time.strptime(final_date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))


path = 'x:/Transfer/Praktikanten/2017-05-Sharon/M02_Modelldaten/Sofia_HW_032015_12/01.01.2015-31.12.2015_2014/22.02.2015-15.04.2015_201410XX/'
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
          f_out = open('NEW_' + file,'w')
          f_in=open(file, 'r').readlines()

          f_out.write(f_in[0])

          for i in range(1, len(f_in)):
              Datum_Uhrzeit= f_in[i].split(';',)[0]
              Datum_Uhrzeit = time.mktime(time.strptime(Datum_Uhrzeit, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))
             if initial <= Datum_Uhrzeit <= final:
                 f_out.write(f_in[i])
f_out.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of your variables contains a space. This is not allowed.

example: `Datum Uhrzeit`=> `Datum_Uhrzeit` (or even better: `datum_uhrzeit`).

Check [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know this.

Comment: I corrected this, now I dont have syntax error.. the code runs but it still doesnt generate new files

Comment: what do you mean by you don't know this? Are you a python programmer?

Comment: No! I am not a programmer at all!

Comment: I really advise you to read the pep8 and try to follow it, you will produce better code which will be readable by everybody with some python experience. (btw, you can upvote my anwser too :) )

Comment: Thanks I already bookmarked it! I upvoted your answer but I have less than 15 reputation so it doesn't show up